# Geocoding city+states as they are periodically added to a google sheet?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a google sheet that uses this [importJSON script](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a) to add a list of cities and states into a google sheet. Rows are added periodically, as cities are added by users on our website (which are reflected on our JSON file).

I'm currently using this hacky code to add lon, lat for each row (C5 and D5 reference the city and state columns, respectively.

```
={
    CONCATENATE(ImportJSON(CONCATENATE(
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",CONCATENATE(C5,",",D5),"&sensor=false"),"/results/geometry/location/lng","noHeaders"
    )),
    CONCATENATE(ImportJSON(CONCATENATE(
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",CONCATENATE(C5,",",D5),"&sensor=false"),"/results/geometry/location/lat","noHeaders"
    ))
}
```

Each time the sheet is reloaded each geocode is recalculated unecessarily-- and the more rows need to be geocoded at once the more errors occur-- what can I do so that a row is only geocoded if the the city/state cells are modified for that row?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this. When I created a sample my spreadsheet only updates when C5 (or D5) is changed. I actually am just using one field for the address though...

```
={
CONCATENATE(ImportJSON(CONCATENATE(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",C5,"&sensor=false"),"/results/geometry/location/lng","noHeaders"
)),
CONCATENATE(ImportJSON(CONCATENATE(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",C5,"&sensor=false"),"/results/geometry/location/lat","noHeaders"
))
}
```

I used the ImportJSON function here... https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164/